# Any 3D issues with latest versions of Asy and Ghostscript?

Tags: 3d, asymptote, ghostscript

I just would like to submit this question:
I have recently updated the versions of asymptote (2.85 now) and ghostscript (gs10.01.1) and since, I'm totally unable to compile my `.tex` file that used to produce embeded 3D pdf files.
I'm using TeXmaker with commands/path defined as :
[image]

The asymptote command being run is

`"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/asy.exe" -f pdf -noview %.asy|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf`

For example, the code generates a poor quality `.pdf` with no interactivity. Years ago I could get 3D embeded `.pdf` with ease :

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}[height=8cm,viewportwidth=\linewidth]
import settings;
import three;
import macros3D;
size(12cm);
real a=6, b=4, c=2, d=1;
currentprojection=orthographic(120*a/3,-120*b,120*2c/3);
transform3 T=shift(0,0,c);
triple A=(0,0,0), B=(a,0,0), C=(a,b,0), D=(0,b,0),
pE=T*A, F=T*B, G=T*C, H=T*D, P=(a-d,0,0);
pen ps=lightmagenta+opacity(.5), pT=bp+linetype("4 4");
draw(A--B--C--G--H--pE--F--G^^pE--A^^F--B,linewidth(bp));
draw(A--D--C^^H--D,pT);
draw(surface(H--D--P--cycle),ps,pT);
draw(surface(H--P--C--cycle),ps,pT);
draw(surface(H--D--C--cycle),ps,pT);
draw(surface(D--P--C--cycle),ps,pT);
label("$A$",A,S); label("$B$",B,SE); label("$C$",C,E);
label("$D$",D,NW); label("$E$",pE,NW+2W); label("$F$",F,SE);
label("$G$",G,E); label("$H$",H,N); label("$P$",P,SW);
cote3D(format("$%f$~cm",a),G,H,unit(H-pE));
cote3D(format("$%f$~cm",b),H,pE,3mm,unit(pE-F));
cote3D(format("$%f$~cm",c),pE,A,3mm,unit(pE-F));
cote3D(format("$%f$~cm",d),P,B,unit(B-F),red);
\end{asy}
\end{document}```

I have been using ASY/Latex for like years I have never had to struggle like that, I must have missed something on the way...
Anyway... could someone provide me with a fonctional example of 3D embeding or any help about that ? 
Thanks a lot !
````

Answer (score 1):

So, it's turned out adding `settings.outformat="pdf";`
and `settings.prc=true;` before loading libraries solved the problem though I would love to know what has changed because we didn't need to do that in past, did we ?